# SQL Server : efficient index to fetch latest inserted/updated rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have a table that has a int auto-increment PK, a `InsertDate` and a `LastUpdated` column, like:

| PersonId | ... ... ... | InsertDate | LastUpdated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 |  | 2020-12-15 | 2021-10-29 |
| 124 |  | 2021-10-29 | null |

There is a index for those 2 "filtered-by" columns and others included columns.

The DW team runs the following query every 5 minutes fetching users created/updated on that window:

```
SELECT {included columns} 
FROM Purchases
WHERE InsertDate > {five minutes ago} 
   OR LastUpdated > {five minutes ago}
```

This query usually returns less than 100 items, and the table is over 150 million records long.

Because the items being queried-for are "extra-fresh", I'm afraid that they are present on the fragmented portion of the index. The index itself is very large with less than 0.05% fragmentation.

I have 2 questions:

- Is the query being hurt by the "fragmentation" of the index?
- Does the ordering of the index (ASC vs DESC) impact the performance?

PS: because of the data sensitivity, I can't replicate this to a non-prod environment and perform tests

Comment: It is more likely being hurt by the fact that you are using one index to do two different jobs.  The phrase `WHERE InsertDate > {five minutes ago} OR LastUpdated > {five minutes ago}` really needs two different indexes.

Comment: so, I should create 2 indexes, one for each filtered column, with the included columns on each?

Comment: Yes.  The question of whether to use include columns is trickier.  For queries on very large tables that are returning very few rows, it may be better to *not* use the INCLUDE feature on the indexes.

Comment: Alternative - you could set LastUpdated  to the same value as InsertDate and then just simplify the logic to use only LastUpdated.

Comment: _I can't replicate_ You must have a way to do this because you should NEVER experiment on a production database.

Answer (score 2):

For this query to work efficiently, you are going to need two indexes, and hope the compiler chooses an index union.

```
Purchases (InsertDate) INCLUDE (OtherColumns)
Purchases (LastUpdated) INCLUDE (OtherColumns)
```

Normally, you should ideally have `DESC`, because even though SQL Server can do a backwards scan, it cannot parallelize it. But in this instance I'm not sure it's a good idea: you only want a few rows so no need to parallelize, and it may cause heavy fragmentation on the first page of the index. Perhaps just do it on `InsertDate DESC`.

In SQL Server 2019, it would be good to have the option `OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = ON` on these indexes.

---

Even with both indexes, you may still get an index scan over the whole table.

You *may* need to rewrite to force an index union

```sql
SELECT PersonId, {included columns} 
  FROM Purchases
  WHERE InsertDate > {five minutes ago}
UNION
SELECT PersonId, {included columns} 
  FROM Purchases
  WHERE LastUpdated > {five minutes ago};
```

Make sure you include the primary key in the column list when unioning

Comment: would your answer change drastically if I were to say that there's one more filter like "OR ProductId in (SELECT productId FROM dbo.Products WHERE productType = @type)" ???

Comment: Makes it more likely that you need to force an index union as shown. You would need a third index on `ProductId` with includes. At some point all the `INCLUDE` columns slow down inserts and updates too much, it's a decision you need to make